# How to remove default drop-down option from JasperReports Server

Tags: jasperserver

I have drop-down input control in *JasperReports Server* which has default option --- like the below image
[image]

I need remove option from its drop-down. Can any one know how to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the input control property to mandatory? That is what I do to get rid of that blank "---" option.